# How can I pass data array in list in angular html dynamically

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am trying to pass data array object to html list dynamically.

```
 <div class="sidebar" *ngFor="let q of obj">
        <h4>Approvals</h4>

        <ul  *ngFor="let c of q.element">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img class="sideico" src="../../../assets/images/icons/BRIA.svg" />{{c}}</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**In ts file**

```
 obj = [
          {
            "element" : "Timesheet",
            "icon": "../../../assets/images/icons/BRIA.svg"
          },
          {
            "element" : "Timesheet",
            "icon": "../../../assets/images/icons/BRIA.svg"
          }
];
```

I am new in Angular. What is wrong?

Comment: your object doesnt include name q.name?

Comment: q.element is a string you can't use ngFor for that. What is the aim of second for loop?  @OM-ॐ

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement properly.

Comment: Guys this is done i have marked the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggqptd) You need just one loop

```
 <div class="sidebar" >
     <h4>Approvals</h4>
     <ul  *ngFor="let q of obj">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img class="sideico" [src]="q.icon | safe : 'url'" />{{q.element}}</a>  
        </li>
    </ul>
           
</div>
```

and use custom safe pipe to bind

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
 
 public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to iterate the list item not the whole list which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to iterate it twice. You just need to iterate it once as shown below:

```
 <div class="sidebar">
        <h4>Approvals</h4>

        <ul>
            <li  *ngFor="let q of obj">
                <a href="#"><img class="sideico" [src]="q?.icon" />{{ q?.element }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why `q?` ?? Can you explain .

Comment: Google `safe navigation operator`. This will help you if the data is undefined or the object does not exist.

Comment: you dont need safe operation there. U are already in loop array if array is null you never enter there. Safe operations is good for object binding.

Comment: Same will go for src ?